# Should "use this later version of the tool that solves your problem: (link)" be deleted?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

*(As noted in Tunaki's comment, one of these examples is actually a bad demonstration of the point I'm asking about. The question in the abstract still stands, though.)*

---

I just hit these LQP reviews:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12809453
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12809455

Both of them are responses to questions complaining that a tool doesn't work. Both reply by providing a link to a newer version of the tool and claiming that in that version the question-askers' bugs are (supposedly) fixed. Both are likely to be deleted by the VLQ reviewers on the basis that they are link-only answers.

Now, it may be that the answerer's fork of the original tool is bad or that its improvements are irrelevant to the questions that were asked, in which case the answer is bad in turn and should be downvoted. I'm ill-equipped to judge (although the wording of one of the answers doesn't inspire much faith that it fixes the problem described in the question). But can it be sane to delete such answers *on the basis of being link-only*?

I understand, and thoroughly approve of, the prohibition on providing answers that are merely links to tutorials or other learning resources. I understand (even if I have some reservations) the community extending that prohibition to answers that are just links to tools - such an answer can almost always be improved by providing basic usage instructions in the answer itself, and that is sufficient to appease the LQP reviewers. But what of this case, where an answerer is providing a link to a *fork* of a tool that the question-asker is *already using* and stating that swapping to the fork will fix the bug that the OP is witnessing?

I don't see what more information could possibly be provided to prevent the deletion of such an answer, yet deleted it will likely be under our current VLQ review culture. Do we truly want to say that pointing out a different version of a tool that fixes an asker's problem is not an allowable answer?

Comment: For the second one where I commented http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12809455, it is not mentioned in the post that it is a fork of a library the OP is already using. It reads as "If you still need [something] there is [this new plugin] [link]", which is link-only for me because there are no explanation as to what that plugin does, how it answers the question and how you're supposed to use it.

Comment: @Tunaki whoops, you are right; I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: I disagree that more information isn't possible.  What was the bug?  What was the fix?  How can it be used?  All this information would provide more depth and actually *really* answer the question.  All the answers on that first question seem to suffer from this.